# Lizmap geoprocessing missing list of processes to run

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-server, wps, lizmap

I installed QGIS Server and lizmap with lizmap-wps-web-client-module and py-qgis-wps. The button appears in lizmap but the select "choose a process to run" is always empty.

Is there something I need to enable in QGIS Server to make the processes list appear when I request this endpoint?request=GetCapabilities&service=WPS, the `<wps:ProcessOfferings/>` is also empty.

I'm using pure QGIS Server and not py-qgis-server.

Should I use the latter instead?

Below are the logs when I start the py-qgis-wps:

```
2023-07-03 14:02:02,262 [963]   INFO    Proxy configuration enabled
2023-07-03 14:02:02,262 [963]   INFO    WPS Server ready
2023-07-03 14:02:02,263 [963]   INFO    Running WPS server on port 0.0.0.0:8081
2023-07-03 14:02:02,264 [963]   WARNING No WPS plugin found in /usr/share/qgis_wps/processing
2023-07-03 14:02:02,266 [963]   WARNING No WPS plugin found in .
2023-07-03 14:02:02,641 [966]   INFO    Starting Qgis application: 3.30.3-'s-Hertogenbosch
2023-07-03 14:02:02,642 [966]   INFO    Setting offscreen mode
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2023-07-03 14:02:03,511 [966]   INFO    [qgis:966] Installing cleanup hook
2023-07-03 14:02:03,536 [966]   INFO    [qgis:966] Qgis application initialized......
2023-07-03 14:02:05,565 [966]   ERROR   [qgis:966] Processing: Problem with OTB installation: OTB folder is not set.
2023-07-03 14:02:05,582 [966]   INFO    [qgis:966] QGis processing initialized
2023-07-03 14:02:05,677 [966]   WARNING No published processes !
2023-07-03 14:02:05,682 [972]   INFO    Starting worker pool
2023-07-03 14:02:05,717 [963]   INFO    Starting supervisor
2023-07-03 14:02:05,718 [963]   INFO    WPS Server ready
2023-07-03 14:02:06,120 [973]   INFO    Starting Qgis application: 3.30.3-'s-Hertogenbosch
2023-07-03 14:02:06,121 [973]   INFO    Setting offscreen mode
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2023-07-03 14:02:06,856 [973]   INFO    [qgis:973] Installing cleanup hook
2023-07-03 14:02:06,857 [973]   INFO    [qgis:973] Qgis application initialized......
2023-07-03 14:02:07,286 [973]   ERROR   [qgis:973] Processing: Problem with OTB installation: OTB folder is not set.
2023-07-03 14:02:07,291 [973]   INFO    [qgis:973] QGis processing initialized
```

Comment: I got it working by exposing the providers through environment variable like `export QGSWPS_PROCESSING_EXPOSED_PROVIDERS="qgis,gdal"`. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, question asked as well on GitHub : https://github.com/3liz/py-qgis-wps/issues/42